# Exporting a frozen graph .pb file in Tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I've beeen trying out the Tensorflow 2 alpha and I have been trying to freeze and export a model to a .pb graphdef file.

In Tensorflow 1 I could do something like this:

```
# Freeze the graph.
frozen_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
    sess,
    sess.graph_def,
    output_node_names)

# Save the frozen graph to .pb file.
with open('model.pb', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(frozen_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

However this doesn't seem possible anymore as convert_variables_to_constants is removed and use of sessions is discouraged.

I looked and found there is the freeze graph util 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py that works with SavedModel exports.

Is there some way to do it within Python still or I am meant to switch and use this tool now?

Comment: Have you seen https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/saved_model ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also faced this same problem while migrating from tensorflow1.x to tensoflow2.0 beta.
This problem can be solved by 2 methods:

1. 1st is to go to the tensflow2.0 docs search for the methods you have used and change the syntax for each line &
2. To use google's tf_ugrade_v2 script

**tf_upgrade_v2 --infile your_tf1_script_file --outfile converted_tf2_file**

You try above command to change your tensorflow1.x script to tensorflow2.0, it will solve all your problem.

Also, you can rename the method (Manual step by refering documentation)
Rename **'tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants' to 'tf.compat.v1.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants'**

The measure problem is that in tensorflow2.0 is that many syntax and function has changed try referring the tensoflow2.0 docs or use the google's tf_upgrade_v2 script

Comment: So no way to do this yet without using the compat module from what you found?

Comment: I guess no there is no other way better than I've answered

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've seen this Tensorflow 2.0 issue, but this response seems to be a work-around:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29253#issuecomment-530782763

Note: this hasn't worked for my nlp model but maybe it will work for you.  The suggested work-around is to use `model.save_weights('weights.h5')` while in TF 2.0 environment.  Then create new environment with TF 1.14 and do all following steps in TF 1.14 env.  Build your model `model = create_model()` and use `model.load_weights('weights.h5')` to load weights back into your model.  Then save entire model with `model.save('final_model.h5')`.  If you manage to have success with the above steps, then follow the rest of the steps in the link to use freeze_graph.

Comment: I did not check my models accuracy but this solution seems to work, great !

Comment: it is suggested to use saved_model instead of h5 in tf 2